# Head first program - ansible

Tags: ansible

I have installed ansible using following commands.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ansible/ansible
sudo apt update
sudo apt install ansible
```

After i followed this [Link](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_modules_general.html).  By using that i created a yml file called test.yml ( the code is shown below)

```
- name: test my new module
  hosts: 127.0.1
  tasks:
  - name: run the new module
    my_test:
      name: 'hello'
      new: true
    register: testout
  - name: dump test output
    debug:
      msg: '{{ testout }}'
```

Then i run `ansible-playbook ./test.yml` . I get following error.

I have no idea where i missed. Any idea is appreciated. Thank you so much.

```
sato:~/play_around_with_ansible$ ansible-playbook ./test.yml
 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note
that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.

The error appears to be in '/home/ven/play_around_with_ansible/test.yml': line 4, column 5, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

  tasks:
  - name: run the new module
    ^ here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the inventory file. Create inventory file in current folder or in the directory of your choice and provide the inventory file path to the ansible-playbook command as below or you can mention the default location of your host file in ansible.cfg

**inventory file contents (sample)**

```
[127.0.1]
localhost ansible_connection=local
```

**command**

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory ./test.yml
```

In the above command `inventory` is the file name with path.

Comment: i have done it but get following error. Any idea is welcome. Thank you. 
https://jmp.sh/YjOP4wE

Answer (score 0):

seems your 'yaml' file was not able to recognize the path for custom module. Even I am new to custom module development. As per the standards you should keep the .py file in "library" directory and create the .ymal file outside of library directory.

This will help your yaml file to look into ./library directory for modules.